# How can I remove() an object after appending it to the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to use jQuery to allow a user to specify a pool of objects which they can then remove.

I want the user to be able to click on the list of objects to add them to the pool, and if they wish to remove any objects from the pool, click on the objects in the pool to do so.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.object').click(function() {
        var typeOfObject = $(this).attr('id'); 
        $('#poolofobjects').append('<td><div class="selected_object">' + typeOfObject + '</div></td>');
    });
    $('.selected_object').click(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    }); 
});
```

Adding an object to the pool of objects works fine, however I cannot seem to remove an object which has been added to the pool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - (*You need to use event delegation*)

```
$("#poolofobjects").on('click',".selected_object",function(){
  $(this).closest("td").remove();
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1):

It's because the object doesn't exist in the page yet when your selector runs, so the event handler isn't added to it.

Use on() instead - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

This code is running, maybe you want deleted td tags of selected_objects. You can try this code;

```
$('.selected_object').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: I can assure you it is not running.